# How to do define-for-syntax in typed racket?

Tags: syntax, macros, racket, typed

This works

```
#lang racket

(begin-for-syntax
  (define (foo n)
    (+ n 3)))
```

So I would also expect this to work

```
#lang typed/racket

(: foo : Real -> Real)
(define-for-syntax (foo n)
  (+ n 3))
```

But if fails with

```
; :: undefined;
;  cannot reference an identifier before its definition
```

After that I tried each of the following in turn in `typed/racket`

```
(define-for-syntax (foo (n : Real)) : Real
  (+ n 3))

(begin-for-syntax
  (: foo (-> Real Real))
  (define (foo n)
    (+ n 3)))

(begin-for-syntax
  (define (foo (n : Real)) : Real
    (+ n 3)))
```

Each failed for one reason or another. Could it be that `typed/racket` can't handle `{begin|define}-for-syntax`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#lang typed/racket

(: foo : Real -> Real)
(define-for-syntax (foo n)
  (+ n 3))
```

fails with:

```
Type Checker: Declaration for `foo' provided, but `foo' has no definition
```

for me, which totally makes sense. `foo` is defined in phase 1, so the type declaration couldn't find its definition in phase 0.

```
(begin-for-syntax
  (: foo (-> Real Real))
  (define (foo n)
    (+ n 3)))
```

is more "correct", but still has a lot of problems. The code is in phase 1, but `:` is imported by `#lang typed/racket` in phase 0, so you get an error:

```
:: undefined
```

However, another major problem is that even if you manage to import `:` in phase 1, the type checker will still not work correctly.

To cut it short, here's how you could make it work.

```
#lang typed/racket

(module for-syntax-mod typed/racket
  (provide foo)
  (: foo (-> Real Real))
  (define (foo n)
    (+ n 3)))

(require (for-syntax 'for-syntax-mod))

(begin-for-syntax (println (foo 10)))
```

This declares `foo` in a submodule `for-syntax-mod` of the language `typed/racket`, so the type checker will now work on this submodule as expected. We then import this submodule at phase 1, so now `foo` is available inside `begin-for-syntax`. Note that code in `begin-for-syntax` is still not type checked statically.

Comment: A follow on question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65447945/3414663